# Ecto: changeset drops update to parent model

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I’m trying the save an update to a record (user) which has a parent (state).  The user record displays fine (in show, edit) including the state.  The user record updates fine for it’s own attributes, but any change to the state selected by the user is not persisted.  When  changing the user’s state from 1 to 2, the user params returned to the controller from the view look fine...from log ->

```
%{"email" => “e@e.com", "first_name" => “Abe",
"last_name" => “Sam", "password" => “foobar", "state_id" => "2"}
```

But when this is passed to the user changeset, it comes back with the change to the state_id dropped...from log ->

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
changes: %{password: "foobar",
password_hash: “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx."},
errors: [], data: #SomeApp.User<>, valid?: true>
```

The update in the controller is:

```
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "user" => user_params}) do
  user = Repo.get!(User, id)
  changeset =  User.changeset(user, user_params)
  case Repo.update(changeset) do
```

…

The relevant changeset code is:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password])
    |> assoc_constraint(:state)
    |> validate_required([:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password])
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 4, max: 100)
    |> put_pass_hash()
  end
```

The schema for the user is:

```
schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :password,  :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    belongs_to :state, SomeApp.State

    timestamps()
  end
```

What’s am i doing wrong here?  Am i missing something in my changeset that casts the user_id from the params into the changeset?  I expect I'm doing something simple and stupid - i've genuinely spent hours trying to read up pick this apart and i'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use the `state_id` from `params`, you'll need to add `:state_id` to the allowed list in the call to `cast`. Without `:state_id` in the allowed list, the value will be ignored, which is what is happening right now.

```
|> cast(params, [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password])
```

should be

```
|> cast(params, [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :state_id])
```

Comment: thankyou - i did try that already, phoenix throws an error on that saying you need to cast associations using cast_assoc.  I'll repro and get the exact error given.  But then trying that throws a separate error complaining that cast_assoc is for children.

Comment: I'm wrong, it totally works now, like you said.  No idea why it didn't work before (maybe i didn't have the assoc_constraint in there).  Huge thankyou -you've made my day!

Comment: I figured it out: i think i previously added :state to the cast instead of :state_id.  I find the naming of the belongs to vs the actual column convention (state vs state_id) not immediately intuitive.  I think i'm doing the right thing though?

Comment: Yes, `state_id` is correct here. `state_id` will always contain an integer. `state` will be the associated `State` model instance, and will only be populated if you preload the association. You'll want to use `state_id` whenever you're modifying that integer value. If you had a form to create a User and create a new State for that user, you'd use `cast_assoc` + `:state`.